# Using aggregate and dplyr, I am returning the same mean value for each group

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, mean

When I use aggregate or dplyr to calculate the mean r value from my grid for each theta and beta combination I return the same value and I cannot find any explanation online for this error.

```
structure(list(theta = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20), beta = c(100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100), replicate = 1:6, r = c(0.0324220694816509, 
0.0315803842788983, 0.0233601310665862, 0.0262786224671214, 0.0182666042902602, 
0.018777001480836), detection = c(174, 103, 183, 210, 133, 263
), prevalence = c(0.025, 0.023, 0.008, 0.161, 0.007, 0.047)), out.attrs = list(
 dim = c(theta = 7L, beta = 7L, replicate = 1000L, r = 1L, 
  detection = 1L), dimnames = list(theta = c("theta= 0.05", 
    "theta= 0.10", "theta= 0.50", "theta= 1.00", "theta= 5.00", 
    "theta=10.00", "theta=20.00"), beta = c("beta=  0.5", "beta=  1.0", 
    "beta=  5.0", "beta= 10.0", "beta= 20.0", "beta= 50.0", "beta=100.0"
    ), replicate = c("replicate=   1", "replicate=   2", "replicate=   3", 
    "replicate=   4", "replicate=   5", "replicate=   6", "replicate=   7", 
    "replicate=   8", "replicate=   9", "replicate=  10", "replicate=  11", 
    "replicate=  12", "replicate=  13", "replicate=  14", "replicate=  15", 
    "replicate=  16", "replicate=  17", "replicate=  18", "replicate=  19", 
    "replicate=  20", "replicate=  21", "replicate=  22", "replicate=  23", 
    "replicate=  24", "replicate=  25", "replicate=  26", "replicate=  27", 
    "replicate=  28", "replicate=  29", "replicate=  30", "replicate=  31", 
    "replicate=  32", "replicate=  33", "replicate=  34", "replicate=  35", 
    "replicate=  36", "replicate=  37", "replicate=  38", "replicate=  39", 
    "replicate=  40", "replicate=  41", "replicate=  42", "replicate=  43", 
    "replicate=  44", "replicate=  45", "replicate=  46", "replicate=  47", 
    "replicate=  48", "replicate=  49", "replicate=  50", "replicate=  51", 
    "replicate=  52", "replicate=  53", "replicate=  54", "replicate=  55", 
    "replicate=  56", "replicate=  57", "replicate=  58", "replicate=  59", 
    "replicate=  60", "replicate=  61", "replicate=  62", "replicate=  63", 
    "replicate=  64", "replicate=  65", "replicate=  66", "replicate=  67", 
    "replicate=  68", "replicate=  69", "replicate=  70", "replicate=  71", 
    "replicate=  72", "replicate=  73", "replicate=  74", "replicate=  75", 
    "replicate=  76", "replicate=  77", "replicate=  78", "replicate=  79", 
    "replicate=  80", "replicate=  81", "replicate=  82", "replicate=  83", 
    "replicate=  84", "replicate=  85", "replicate=  86", "replicate=  87", 
    "replicate=  88", "replicate=  89", "replicate=  90", "replicate=  91", 
    "replicate=  92", "replicate=  93", "replicate=  94", "replicate=  95", 
    "replicate=  96", "replicate=  97", "replicate=  98", "replicate=  99", 
    "replicate= 100", "replicate= 101", "replicate= 102", "replicate= 103", 
    "replicate= 104", "replicate= 105", "replicate= 106", "replicate= 107", 
    "replicate= 108", "replicate= 109", "replicate= 110", "replicate= 111", 
    "replicate= 112", "replicate= 113", "replicate= 114", "replicate= 115", 
    "replicate= 116", "replicate= 117", "replicate= 118", "replicate= 119", 
    "replicate= 120", "replicate= 121", "replicate= 122", "replicate= 123", 
    "replicate= 124", "replicate= 125", "replicate= 126", "replicate= 127", 
    "replicate= 128", "replicate= 129", "replicate= 130", "replicate= 131", 
    "replicate= 132", "replicate= 133", "replicate= 134", "replicate= 135", 
    "replicate= 136", "replicate= 137", "replicate= 138", "replicate= 139", 
    "replicate= 140", "replicate= 141", "replicate= 142", "replicate= 143", 
    "replicate= 144", "replicate= 145", "replicate= 146", "replicate= 147", 
    "replicate= 148", "replicate= 149", "replicate= 150", "replicate= 151", 
    "replicate= 152", "replicate= 153", "replicate= 154", "replicate= 155", 
    "replicate= 156", "replicate= 157", "replicate= 158", "replicate= 159", 
    "replicate= 160", "replicate= 161", "replicate= 162", "replicate= 163", 
    "replicate= 164", "replicate= 165", "replicate= 166", "replicate= 167", 
    "replicate= 168", "replicate= 169", "replicate= 170", "replicate= 171", 
    "replicate= 172", "replicate= 173", "replicate= 174", "replicate= 175", 
    "replicate= 176", "replicate= 177", "replicate= 178", "replicate= 179", 
    "replicate= 180", "replicate= 181", "replicate= 182", "replicate= 183", 
    "replicate= 184", "replicate= 185", "replicate= 186", "replicate= 187", 
    "replicate= 188", "replicate= 189", "replicate= 190", "replicate= 191", 
    "replicate= 192", "replicate= 193", "replicate= 194", "replicate= 195", 
    "replicate= 196", "replicate= 197", "replicate= 198", "replicate= 199", 
    "replicate= 200", "replicate= 201", "replicate= 202", "replicate= 203", 
    "replicate= 204", "replicate= 205", "replicate= 206", "replicate= 207", 
    "replicate= 208", "replicate= 209", "replicate= 210", "replicate= 211", 
    "replicate= 212", "replicate= 213", "replicate= 214", "replicate= 215", 
    "replicate= 216", "replicate= 217", "replicate= 218", "replicate= 219", 
    "replicate= 220", "replicate= 221", "replicate= 222", "replicate= 223", 
    "replicate= 224", "replicate= 225", "replicate= 226", "replicate= 227", 
    "replicate= 228", "replicate= 229", "replicate= 230", "replicate= 231", 
    "replicate= 232", "replicate= 233", "replicate= 234", "replicate= 235", 
    "replicate= 236", "replicate= 237", "replicate= 238", "replicate= 239", 
    "replicate= 240", "replicate= 241", "replicate= 242", "replicate= 243", 
    "replicate= 244", "replicate= 245", "replicate= 246", "replicate= 247", 
    "replicate= 248", "replicate= 249", "replicate= 250", "replicate= 251", 
    "replicate= 252", "replicate= 253", "replicate= 254", "replicate= 255", 
    "replicate= 256", "replicate= 257", "replicate= 258", "replicate= 259", 
    "replicate= 260", "replicate= 261", "replicate= 262", "replicate= 263", 
    "replicate= 264", "replicate= 265", "replicate= 266", "replicate= 267", 
    "replicate= 268", "replicate= 269", "replicate= 270", "replicate= 271", 
    "replicate= 272", "replicate= 273", "replicate= 274", "replicate= 275", 
    "replicate= 276", "replicate= 277", "replicate= 278", "replicate= 279", 
    "replicate= 280", "replicate= 281", "replicate= 282", "replicate= 283", 
    "replicate= 284", "replicate= 285", "replicate= 286", "replicate= 287", 
    "replicate= 288", "replicate= 289", "replicate= 290", "replicate= 291", 
    "replicate= 292", "replicate= 293", "replicate= 294", "replicate= 295", 
    "replicate= 296", "replicate= 297", "replicate= 298", "replicate= 299", 
    "replicate= 300", "replicate= 301", "replicate= 302", "replicate= 303", 
    "replicate= 304", "replicate= 305", "replicate= 306", "replicate= 307", 
    "replicate= 308", "replicate= 309", "replicate= 310", "replicate= 311", 
    "replicate= 312", "replicate= 313", "replicate= 314", "replicate= 315", 
    "replicate= 316", "replicate= 317", "replicate= 318", "replicate= 319", 
    "replicate= 320", "replicate= 321", "replicate= 322", "replicate= 323", 
    "replicate= 324", "replicate= 325", "replicate= 326", "replicate= 327", 
    "replicate= 328", "replicate= 329", "replicate= 330", "replicate= 331", 
    "replicate= 332", "replicate= 333", "replicate= 334", "replicate= 335", 
    "replicate= 336", "replicate= 337", "replicate= 338", "replicate= 339", 
    "replicate= 340", "replicate= 341", "replicate= 342", "replicate= 343", 
    "replicate= 344", "replicate= 345", "replicate= 346", "replicate= 347", 
    "replicate= 348", "replicate= 349", "replicate= 350", "replicate= 351", 
    "replicate= 352", "replicate= 353", "replicate= 354", "replicate= 355", 
    "replicate= 356", "replicate= 357", "replicate= 358", "replicate= 359", 
    "replicate= 360", "replicate= 361", "replicate= 362", "replicate= 363", 
    "replicate= 364", "replicate= 365", "replicate= 366", "replicate= 367", 
    "replicate= 368", "replicate= 369", "replicate= 370", "replicate= 371", 
    "replicate= 372", "replicate= 373", "replicate= 374", "replicate= 375", 
    "replicate= 376", "replicate= 377", "replicate= 378", "replicate= 379", 
    "replicate= 380", "replicate= 381", "replicate= 382", "replicate= 383", 
    "replicate= 384", "replicate= 385", "replicate= 386", "replicate= 387", 
    "replicate= 388", "replicate= 389", "replicate= 390", "replicate= 391", 
    "replicate= 392", "replicate= 393", "replicate= 394", "replicate= 395", 
    "replicate= 396", "replicate= 397", "replicate= 398", "replicate= 399", 
    "replicate= 400", "replicate= 401", "replicate= 402", "replicate= 403", 
    "replicate= 404", "replicate= 405", "replicate= 406", "replicate= 407", 
    "replicate= 408", "replicate= 409", "replicate= 410", "replicate= 411", 
    "replicate= 412", "replicate= 413", "replicate= 414", "replicate= 415", 
    "replicate= 416", "replicate= 417", "replicate= 418", "replicate= 419", 
    "replicate= 420", "replicate= 421", "replicate= 422", "replicate= 423", 
    "replicate= 424", "replicate= 425", "replicate= 426", "replicate= 427", 
    "replicate= 428", "replicate= 429", "replicate= 430", "replicate= 431", 
    "replicate= 432", "replicate= 433", "replicate= 434", "replicate= 435", 
    "replicate= 436", "replicate= 437", "replicate= 438", "replicate= 439", 
    "replicate= 440", "replicate= 441", "replicate= 442", "replicate= 443", 
    "replicate= 444", "replicate= 445", "replicate= 446", "replicate= 447", 
    "replicate= 448", "replicate= 449", "replicate= 450", "replicate= 451", 
    "replicate= 452", "replicate= 453", "replicate= 454", "replicate= 455", 
    "replicate= 456", "replicate= 457", "replicate= 458", "replicate= 459", 
    "replicate= 460", "replicate= 461", "replicate= 462", "replicate= 463", 
    "replicate= 464", "replicate= 465", "replicate= 466", "replicate= 467", 
    "replicate= 468", "replicate= 469", "replicate= 470", "replicate= 471", 
    "replicate= 472", "replicate= 473", "replicate= 474", "replicate= 475", 
    "replicate= 476", "replicate= 477", "replicate= 478", "replicate= 479", 
    "replicate= 480", "replicate= 481", "replicate= 482", "replicate= 483", 
    "replicate= 484", "replicate= 485", "replicate= 486", "replicate= 487", 
    "replicate= 488", "replicate= 489", "replicate= 490", "replicate= 491", 
    "replicate= 492", "replicate= 493", "replicate= 494", "replicate= 495", 
    "replicate= 496", "replicate= 497", "replicate= 498", "replicate= 499", 
    "replicate= 500", "replicate= 501", "replicate= 502", "replicate= 503", 
    "replicate= 504", "replicate= 505", "replicate= 506", "replicate= 507", 
    "replicate= 508", "replicate= 509", "replicate= 510", "replicate= 511", 
    "replicate= 512", "replicate= 513", "replicate= 514", "replicate= 515", 
    "replicate= 516", "replicate= 517", "replicate= 518", "replicate= 519", 
    "replicate= 520", "replicate= 521", "replicate= 522", "replicate= 523", 
    "replicate= 524", "replicate= 525", "replicate= 526", "replicate= 527", 
    "replicate= 528", "replicate= 529", "replicate= 530", "replicate= 531", 
    "replicate= 532", "replicate= 533", "replicate= 534", "replicate= 535", 
    "replicate= 536", "replicate= 537", "replicate= 538", "replicate= 539", 
    "replicate= 540", "replicate= 541", "replicate= 542", "replicate= 543", 
    "replicate= 544", "replicate= 545", "replicate= 546", "replicate= 547", 
    "replicate= 548", "replicate= 549", "replicate= 550", "replicate= 551", 
    "replicate= 552", "replicate= 553", "replicate= 554", "replicate= 555", 
    "replicate= 556", "replicate= 557", "replicate= 558", "replicate= 559", 
    "replicate= 560", "replicate= 561", "replicate= 562", "replicate= 563", 
    "replicate= 564", "replicate= 565", "replicate= 566", "replicate= 567", 
    "replicate= 568", "replicate= 569", "replicate= 570", "replicate= 571", 
    "replicate= 572", "replicate= 573", "replicate= 574", "replicate= 575", 
    "replicate= 576", "replicate= 577", "replicate= 578", "replicate= 579", 
    "replicate= 580", "replicate= 581", "replicate= 582", "replicate= 583", 
    "replicate= 584", "replicate= 585", "replicate= 586", "replicate= 587", 
    "replicate= 588", "replicate= 589", "replicate= 590", "replicate= 591", 
    "replicate= 592", "replicate= 593", "replicate= 594", "replicate= 595", 
    "replicate= 596", "replicate= 597", "replicate= 598", "replicate= 599", 
    "replicate= 600", "replicate= 601", "replicate= 602", "replicate= 603", 
    "replicate= 604", "replicate= 605", "replicate= 606", "replicate= 607", 
    "replicate= 608", "replicate= 609", "replicate= 610", "replicate= 611", 
    "replicate= 612", "replicate= 613", "replicate= 614", "replicate= 615", 
    "replicate= 616", "replicate= 617", "replicate= 618", "replicate= 619", 
    "replicate= 620", "replicate= 621", "replicate= 622", "replicate= 623", 
    "replicate= 624", "replicate= 625", "replicate= 626", "replicate= 627", 
    "replicate= 628", "replicate= 629", "replicate= 630", "replicate= 631", 
    "replicate= 632", "replicate= 633", "replicate= 634", "replicate= 635", 
    "replicate= 636", "replicate= 637", "replicate= 638", "replicate= 639", 
    "replicate= 640", "replicate= 641", "replicate= 642", "replicate= 643", 
    "replicate= 644", "replicate= 645", "replicate= 646", "replicate= 647", 
    "replicate= 648", "replicate= 649", "replicate= 650", "replicate= 651", 
    "replicate= 652", "replicate= 653", "replicate= 654", "replicate= 655", 
    "replicate= 656", "replicate= 657", "replicate= 658", "replicate= 659", 
    "replicate= 660", "replicate= 661", "replicate= 662", "replicate= 663", 
    "replicate= 664", "replicate= 665", "replicate= 666", "replicate= 667", 
    "replicate= 668", "replicate= 669", "replicate= 670", "replicate= 671", 
    "replicate= 672", "replicate= 673", "replicate= 674", "replicate= 675", 
    "replicate= 676", "replicate= 677", "replicate= 678", "replicate= 679", 
    "replicate= 680", "replicate= 681", "replicate= 682", "replicate= 683", 
    "replicate= 684", "replicate= 685", "replicate= 686", "replicate= 687", 
    "replicate= 688", "replicate= 689", "replicate= 690", "replicate= 691", 
    "replicate= 692", "replicate= 693", "replicate= 694", "replicate= 695", 
    "replicate= 696", "replicate= 697", "replicate= 698", "replicate= 699", 
    "replicate= 700", "replicate= 701", "replicate= 702", "replicate= 703", 
    "replicate= 704", "replicate= 705", "replicate= 706", "replicate= 707", 
    "replicate= 708", "replicate= 709", "replicate= 710", "replicate= 711", 
    "replicate= 712", "replicate= 713", "replicate= 714", "replicate= 715", 
    "replicate= 716", "replicate= 717", "replicate= 718", "replicate= 719", 
    "replicate= 720", "replicate= 721", "replicate= 722", "replicate= 723", 
    "replicate= 724", "replicate= 725", "replicate= 726", "replicate= 727", 
    "replicate= 728", "replicate= 729", "replicate= 730", "replicate= 731", 
    "replicate= 732", "replicate= 733", "replicate= 734", "replicate= 735", 
    "replicate= 736", "replicate= 737", "replicate= 738", "replicate= 739", 
    "replicate= 740", "replicate= 741", "replicate= 742", "replicate= 743", 
    "replicate= 744", "replicate= 745", "replicate= 746", "replicate= 747", 
    "replicate= 748", "replicate= 749", "replicate= 750", "replicate= 751", 
    "replicate= 752", "replicate= 753", "replicate= 754", "replicate= 755", 
    "replicate= 756", "replicate= 757", "replicate= 758", "replicate= 759", 
    "replicate= 760", "replicate= 761", "replicate= 762", "replicate= 763", 
    "replicate= 764", "replicate= 765", "replicate= 766", "replicate= 767", 
    "replicate= 768", "replicate= 769", "replicate= 770", "replicate= 771", 
    "replicate= 772", "replicate= 773", "replicate= 774", "replicate= 775", 
    "replicate= 776", "replicate= 777", "replicate= 778", "replicate= 779", 
    "replicate= 780", "replicate= 781", "replicate= 782", "replicate= 783", 
    "replicate= 784", "replicate= 785", "replicate= 786", "replicate= 787", 
    "replicate= 788", "replicate= 789", "replicate= 790", "replicate= 791", 
    "replicate= 792", "replicate= 793", "replicate= 794", "replicate= 795", 
    "replicate= 796", "replicate= 797", "replicate= 798", "replicate= 799", 
    "replicate= 800", "replicate= 801", "replicate= 802", "replicate= 803", 
    "replicate= 804", "replicate= 805", "replicate= 806", "replicate= 807", 
    "replicate= 808", "replicate= 809", "replicate= 810", "replicate= 811", 
    "replicate= 812", "replicate= 813", "replicate= 814", "replicate= 815", 
    "replicate= 816", "replicate= 817", "replicate= 818", "replicate= 819", 
    "replicate= 820", "replicate= 821", "replicate= 822", "replicate= 823", 
    "replicate= 824", "replicate= 825", "replicate= 826", "replicate= 827", 
    "replicate= 828", "replicate= 829", "replicate= 830", "replicate= 831", 
    "replicate= 832", "replicate= 833", "replicate= 834", "replicate= 835", 
    "replicate= 836", "replicate= 837", "replicate= 838", "replicate= 839", 
    "replicate= 840", "replicate= 841", "replicate= 842", "replicate= 843", 
    "replicate= 844", "replicate= 845", "replicate= 846", "replicate= 847", 
    "replicate= 848", "replicate= 849", "replicate= 850", "replicate= 851", 
    "replicate= 852", "replicate= 853", "replicate= 854", "replicate= 855", 
    "replicate= 856", "replicate= 857", "replicate= 858", "replicate= 859", 
    "replicate= 860", "replicate= 861", "replicate= 862", "replicate= 863", 
    "replicate= 864", "replicate= 865", "replicate= 866", "replicate= 867", 
    "replicate= 868", "replicate= 869", "replicate= 870", "replicate= 871", 
    "replicate= 872", "replicate= 873", "replicate= 874", "replicate= 875", 
    "replicate= 876", "replicate= 877", "replicate= 878", "replicate= 879", 
    "replicate= 880", "replicate= 881", "replicate= 882", "replicate= 883", 
    "replicate= 884", "replicate= 885", "replicate= 886", "replicate= 887", 
    "replicate= 888", "replicate= 889", "replicate= 890", "replicate= 891", 
    "replicate= 892", "replicate= 893", "replicate= 894", "replicate= 895", 
    "replicate= 896", "replicate= 897", "replicate= 898", "replicate= 899", 
    "replicate= 900", "replicate= 901", "replicate= 902", "replicate= 903", 
    "replicate= 904", "replicate= 905", "replicate= 906", "replicate= 907", 
    "replicate= 908", "replicate= 909", "replicate= 910", "replicate= 911", 
    "replicate= 912", "replicate= 913", "replicate= 914", "replicate= 915", 
    "replicate= 916", "replicate= 917", "replicate= 918", "replicate= 919", 
    "replicate= 920", "replicate= 921", "replicate= 922", "replicate= 923", 
    "replicate= 924", "replicate= 925", "replicate= 926", "replicate= 927", 
    "replicate= 928", "replicate= 929", "replicate= 930", "replicate= 931", 
    "replicate= 932", "replicate= 933", "replicate= 934", "replicate= 935", 
    "replicate= 936", "replicate= 937", "replicate= 938", "replicate= 939", 
    "replicate= 940", "replicate= 941", "replicate= 942", "replicate= 943", 
    "replicate= 944", "replicate= 945", "replicate= 946", "replicate= 947", 
    "replicate= 948", "replicate= 949", "replicate= 950", "replicate= 951", 
    "replicate= 952", "replicate= 953", "replicate= 954", "replicate= 955", 
    "replicate= 956", "replicate= 957", "replicate= 958", "replicate= 959", 
    "replicate= 960", "replicate= 961", "replicate= 962", "replicate= 963", 
    "replicate= 964", "replicate= 965", "replicate= 966", "replicate= 967", 
    "replicate= 968", "replicate= 969", "replicate= 970", "replicate= 971", 
    "replicate= 972", "replicate= 973", "replicate= 974", "replicate= 975", 
    "replicate= 976", "replicate= 977", "replicate= 978", "replicate= 979", 
    "replicate= 980", "replicate= 981", "replicate= 982", "replicate= 983", 
    "replicate= 984", "replicate= 985", "replicate= 986", "replicate= 987", 
    "replicate= 988", "replicate= 989", "replicate= 990", "replicate= 991", 
    "replicate= 992", "replicate= 993", "replicate= 994", "replicate= 995", 
    "replicate= 996", "replicate= 997", "replicate= 998", "replicate= 999", 
    "replicate=1000"), r = "r=NA", detection = "detection=NA")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the head for my large data set, when I apply the function, either

```
meanr2<-aggregate(r~beta+theta,grid,mean)
```

or

```
DT<-data.table(grid)

DT%>% group_by(grid$beta,grid$theta)%>%summarise(grid$r=mean(x))
```

I get the same value for r for each row, which is incorrect as the r value should be different for each row.

```
10, 20, 50, 100, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 20, 
50, 100, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 
0.5, 1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100), theta = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 
0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20), 
    r = c(0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 
    0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 
    0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 
    0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 
    0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 
    0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 
    0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 
    0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 
    0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 
    0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 
    0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 
    0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 
    0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 
    0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 
    0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 
    0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 0.0154762117755727, 
    0.0154762117755727)), row.names = c(NA, -49L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try `df %>% group_by(theta,beta) %>% summarise(M=mean(r))`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, returns only one value. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: You `dput()` data has only 20 rows. That is strage. Could you please check.

Comment: Hi Duck, which dput() do you mean, the top one is the head for my big data table and the bottom one is the output from aggregate(). I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The top one, if you copy and paste you only get 20 rows!

Comment: Oh okay, that is strange, I only get six rows. I used head() to give a general idea of my data frame, (it has 49000 rows!). So I am suprised that you get 20!

Comment: Yeah, there is something strange. Try `mutate()` instead of `sumamrise`!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220621/discussion-between-opensauce-and-duck).